# Jira Server: Button for creating a linked issue

Tags: jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

In our project, one Jira issue of type Requirement is linked to n issues of type Functional Specification (FS). What I need is a button on a Requirement issue to create a FS issue and then link it automatically in a certain way to the Requirement issue.

By the way, we are still using Jira Server. We will probably move to Jira Cloud in some years (because Jira Server is discontinued), but I guess we will need to resolve this problem again when it happens.

Approaches:

- There is a “Constrained create issue dialog” **fragment** in Adaptavist ScriptRunner. With this I can have a “create FS” button which works as it creates an issue with the specified type. But how can I link the new issue to the original one?
- There is a “Clones an issue, and links” **listener** in Adaptavist ScriptRunner which can be specified to do exactly what I want including the correct linking. Is it possible to connect it somehow to a button? Currently I am listening to if a new comment body equals "createFS", which is not really an ideal solution. But at least I am able to delete the comment automatically. Condition:
  `issue.issueType.name == 'Requirement' && event.getComment().getBody().equals('createFS') && com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager().delete(event.getComment())`

Comment: So basically, do you want to link FS issues to the Requirement with a button; or want to create FS issues from Requirement type and link them to the Requirement?

Comment: @stuck I want to create a FS issue from a Requirement issue and also (in one go) automatically link the FS issue to the Requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using Adaptavist ScriptRunner for Jira

#### First step: a fragment to create the issue

Jira administration → Manage apps → Fragments → Create Script Fragments → Constrained create issue dialog with

| Name | Value | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| What section should this go in | `operations-work` | to have the button respectively menu item it in the “More” menu of the current issue |
| Key | `create-linked-fs` | needed to be referenced in the second step |
| Weight | `1` | Place in the menu in case you specify more custom buttons |
| Condition | `issue.issueType.name == 'Requirement'` | matching type of current issue |
| Issue Type | `Functional Specification` | type of the new issue |

#### Second step: a behaviour to link the two issues

Behaviours → Add Behaviour

- **Initialiser:**

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

if (getBehaviourContextId() == "create-linked-fs") {
    getFieldById("project-field").setReadOnly(true)
    getFieldById("issuetype-field").setReadOnly(true)
    def contextIssue = issueManager.getIssueObject(getContextIssueId())
    getFieldById("issuelinks-linktype").setFormValue("trace up to").setReadOnly(true)
    getFieldById("issuelinks-issues").setFormValue(contextIssue.key).setReadOnly(true)
}
```

- **Mapping:**
  Select which project(s) and issue type(s) apply.

Comment: You need also to add a mapping to the behavior to get it work.

Comment: See Adaptavist documentation here: https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/script-fragments/built-in-fragments/create-constrained-issue

Comment: If you wish to set by default the target project as the same as the source project you can add in the behaviour initialiser: getFieldById("project-field").setFormValue(contextIssue.projectObject.name) I wish it were the default value and the project not mandatory.